# Enlargement and centering PDF for printing

Tags: pdf, printing, zoom

I have a PDF doc, 1 page per sheet, on the Letter 8.5x11 paper size, and with big 2-inch margins (apparently, the docs has originally been designed to be cropped to a booklet with a custom page size).

I'm trying to print 2 pages per sheet with the landscape orientation, and double-sided (to save paper and ink).

How can I enlarge a text box to about 120%, center it (because of the huge margins) and print 2 pages per sheet, double-sided?